# Simpletip plugin not working

Tags: jquery, simpletip

Ok I'm stumped.  I have been trying to use [Simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) to create a tooltip on click event so that tooltips are useful on a mobile device.

I can't for the life of me get anything to happen.  Have created an example at http://jsfiddle.net/JrDYN/5/ of the unsuccessful attempt.

Is anyone able to spot why this doesn't work?

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here. For starters, you're using object literal syntax inside the call to `hover` but the code you're passing in is a function body:

```
$(".trafficlights").hover({
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
});
```

And you had a typo in the `simpletip` call (the S was capitalized). This works in the jsFiddle example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trafficlights").simpletip({
         content: 'Simple Tip'
    });
    $(".trafficlights").hover(function () {
        $(this).css('background', 'green')
    });        
});
```

Here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/wKNZb/) of your jsFiddle.

For future reference, the way I figured this out was to pull up Chrome's developer tools (hit F12) and look at the console tab. Chrome was reporting a syntax error. That helped me spot the missing `function` keyword.

Once I had that in place, I was still getting an error, so I commented out the call to `simpletip` and the error went away. Bingo, syntax error in the `simpletip` section, an object didn't exist. A quick peek at the documentation confirmed that the `simpletip` call needed to be capitalized. There you have it.

Comment: Hi Josh,Thanks for the help.
I had actually put that capital S in there whilst trying everything and anything to make it work. :)   

I have taken your advice and tried it on my actual page (sorry it's an intranet site so I can't give you a link) and it is still not working.  Well, I can see the classes being added in the Chrome inspector but I can't see the tooltip on the page. 

I do have Lightbox 2.0 (with the jQuery.noconflict fix) running on that same page which seems to be affecting some things....perhaps if I swap out the Lightbox with a jQuery solution I might make some progress.

Comment: I would try making a copy of your page, if that's possible, and simplifying the code until you isolate the problem. In the Fiddle I noticed that it looks like the tooltip needs some CSS applied (it was just displaying right on top of the green/red box). I suspect some of your CSS is hiding it inadvertently. Try commenting out CSS links and see if you can find the tooltip anywhere on the page.

Comment: Hi Josh,  yes I have been slowly doing that (although today I have moved onto other parts of the project).  I have noted that the popup doesn't appear to work on the <img> tag.  When I apply it to a DIV it works, yet I haven't seen anywhere in the documentation that states an <img> tag should not work.  It should just be a case of specifying it in the jquery descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and it looks like simpletip places the tooltip html inside the img tag. Because of this, it's not recognized and handled by the browser and you don't see the tooltip appear.

I worked around it by wrapping the image inside `<a href="javascript:;"></a>` and applying simpletip to the link.